# How can i re-initalise some variable with object value,to array of object without using another variable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have variable called obj.If i want to to have array of object i will use another variable for example:

```
 let obj = {
      name:"John"
    }

    let arr = [obj];
    console.log(arr);
```

and i will get

```
[
   { name:"John"}
]
```

is there any ES6 JS shorthand for this,without using another variable ?

for example if i have only

```
 let obj = {
      name:"John"
    }
```

how can i get

```
[
   { name:"John"}
]
```

without using another variable

Comment: Are you asking if you can just create the `arr` without creating `obj` first? If so, the answer is yes.

Comment: Isnt this pretty short already?

Comment: `let arr = [{name:"John"}]`? or if you want `obj` to be become an array, given that it is currently an object: `obj = [obj]`. Although note that the later is potentially confusing.

Comment: How you mean,later isn't particularly readable ?

Comment: @Trajce12: What I mean is that you have a variable that was an object and at some point it becomes an array and that's potentially confusing when you  (or somebody else) looks at the code later. So just to avoid having another variable named `arr`, you've made you code potentially harder to read and follow. Worse if you were to somehow end up accidentally hitting the line `obj = [obj]` again, well now obj is an array inside an array.

Answer (score 0):

hard to tell what you are asking but this would create what you created with only one variable:

```
let arr = [{ name:"John"}];
```